# Avoid filesort with INNER JOIN + ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by, filesort

I've been reading other posts but I didn't managed to fix my query.

Using `DESC` order the query is x20 times slower, I must improve that.
This is the query:

```
SELECT posts.post_id, posts.post_b_id, posts.post_title, posts.post_cont, posts.thumb, posts.post_user, boards.board_title_l, boards.board_title
FROM posts
INNER JOIN follow ON posts.post_b_id = follow.board_id
INNER JOIN boards ON posts.post_b_id = boards.board_id
WHERE follow.user_id =1
ORDER BY posts.post_id DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

And these are the tables (Updated):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
`post_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`post_b_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`post_title` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`post_cont` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`post_mintxt` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`post_type` char(3) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`thumb` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`post_user` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`published` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`post_ip` varchar(94) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`post_ip_dat` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`post_up` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`post_down` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
 KEY `post_b_id` (`post_b_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=405 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `boards` (
`board_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`board_title_l` varchar(19) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`board_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`board_title` varchar(19) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`board_user` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`board_txt` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
`board_img` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
`board_vid` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
`board_desc` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`board_mod_p` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`board_ip` varchar(94) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`board_dat_ip` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`board_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `board_title_l` (`board_title_l`),
 KEY `board_user_id` (`board_user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=89 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `follow` (
`user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`board_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`board_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Using default `ASC` order it only uses **index and where**, with `DESC` uses **index,  where, temporary and filesort.**

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key         key_len  ref                rows    filtered    Extra   
 1  SIMPLE      follow  ref     user_id         user_id     4        const              2       100.00      Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
 1  SIMPLE      boards  eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY     4   xxxx.follow.board_id    1       100.00  
 1  SIMPLE      posts   ref     post_b_id       post_b_id   4   xxxx.boards.board_id    3       100.00      Using where
```

How I can make the query receiving the results in `DESC` order without filesort and temporary.

**UPDATE:** I made a new query, no temporary or filesort, but **type: index**, filtered: 7340.00. Almost as fast as `ASC` order if the posts are at the end of the table, but slow if the posts that is searching are at the beginning. So seems better but it's not enough.

```
SELECT posts.post_id, posts.post_b_id, posts.post_title, posts.post_cont, posts.thumb, posts.post_user, boards.board_title_l, boards.board_title 
FROM posts INNER JOIN boards ON posts.post_b_id = boards.board_id
WHERE posts.post_b_id
IN (
 SELECT follow.board_id
 FROM follow
 WHERE follow.user_id = 1
)
ORDER BY posts.post_id DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Explain:

```
id  select_type        table    type    possible_keys   key        key_len   ref                rows    filtered    Extra   
 1  PRIMARY            posts    index   post_b_id       PRIMARY        8     NULL                10     7340.00    Using where
 1  PRIMARY            boards   eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY        4    xxxx.posts.post_b_id 1      100.00  
 2  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  follow  eq_ref  user_id         user_id        8     const,func          1      100.00     Using index
```

**UPDATE:** Explain for the query from [dened's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30420677/2266855):

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys    key       key_len  ref              rows   filtered    Extra   
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>ALL   NULL             NULL      NULL     NULL             10     100.00  
1   PRIMARY     posts   eq_ref  PRIMARY,post_b_id PRIMARY  4        sq.post_id       1      100.00      
1   PRIMARY     boards  eq_ref  PRIMARY          PRIMARY   4    xxxx.posts.post_b_id 1      100.00  
2   DERIVED     follow  ref     PRIMARY          PRIMARY   4                         1      100.00      Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED     posts   ref     post_b_id        post_b_id 4    xxxx.follow.board_id 6      100.00      Using index
```

**Times:**

```
Original query no order (ASC):              0.187500 seconds
Original query DESC:                        2.812500 seconds
Second query posts at the end (DESC):       0.218750 seconds
Second query posts at the beginning (DESC): 3.293750 seconds
dened's query DESC:                         0.421875 seconds 
dened's query no order (ASC):               0.323750 seconds
```

Interesting note, if I add `ORDER BY ASC` is as slow as `DESC`.

Alter the table order will be a god way, but as I said in the comments I wasn't able to do that.

Comment: This looks good. Not sure what you can do :-(

Comment: You could add a descending index on post_id

Comment: "InnoDB always orders table rows according to the clustered index." I tried ALTER TABLE  `posts` ORDER BY  `post_id` DESC ; and it stays ASC anyways, others engines can have DESC order but if you insert or delete any row it does not maintain the order.

Comment: Why you need a composite primary key (`post_id`,`post_b_id`) for the `posts` table? `post_id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT` therefore it is unique. Why not make `post_id` a primary key in this case?

Comment: At this point I don't remember, I changed it. I think I added post_b_id key yesterday testing.

Comment: @Vixxs, if so, can you please change `posts` primary key back to `(post_id)`?

Comment: Updated, PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can help MySQL optimizer by moving all the filtering work to a subquery that accesses only indices (manipulating indices is usually much faster than manipulating other data), and fetching rest of the data in the outermost query:

```
SELECT posts.post_id,
       posts.post_b_id,
       posts.post_title,
       posts.post_cont,
       posts.thumb,
       posts.post_user,
       boards.board_title_l,
       boards.board_title
FROM   (SELECT post_id
        FROM   posts
               JOIN follow
                 ON posts.post_b_id = follow.board_id
        WHERE  follow.user_id = 1
        ORDER  BY post_id DESC
        LIMIT  10) sq
       JOIN posts
         ON posts.post_id = sq.post_id
       JOIN boards
         ON boards.board_id = posts.post_b_id
```

Note that I omit `ORDER BY posts.post_id DESC` from the outer query, because it is usually faster to sort the final result in your code rather than sorting using a MySQL query (MySQL often uses *filesort* for that).

P.S. You can replace the unique key in the `follow` table with a primary key.

Comment: Follow key made primary. Tested you query, stable speed no matter where posts are, not as fast as original query no order, but perhaps thats not possible.

Comment: @Vixxs, I changed the query slightly. This should be a bit more faster. This version assumes the primary key of `posts` is just `(post_id)`, but not `(post_id, post_b_id)`.

Comment: @Vixxs, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it helped to solve your problem. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). You can also upvote any answer if it was helpful for you. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Comment: Sure it is helpful, and I will mark your answer as accepted if there is not any other better answer, I'll remember. I'm just going to work in this query a little more.

Comment: @Vixxs, also try to add unique key `(post_b_id, post_id)` (in this specific column order) to `posts`. There is a chance that this will make my query faster.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the [`sort_buffer_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size) parameter will increase the amount of memory MySQL uses before resorting to a temporary disk file and should help considerably.

Comment: Not lucky with that, all these tables are less than 250kb together, I increased the sort_buffer_size, and other buffers (from 1mb) to 16mb, on xampp, same results.