# How to avoid FileSort when using LEFT JOIN + ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, filesort

mysql-5.6.24-win32.1432006610

I have two simple tables, `TUser(id, name)` and `TMessage(id, uid, message)`. `TUser` holds the users, and `TMessage` holds messages of users.

The SQL is as below, also see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f099

```
CREATE TABLE TUser(
    id     INT UNSIGNED     PRIMARY KEY    NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name   VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE TMessage(
    id      INT UNSIGNED    PRIMARY KEY    NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    uid     INT UNSIGNED    NOT NULL,
    message VARCHAR(256)    NOT NULL
);


CREATE INDEX TMessageIndexUid ON TMessage(uid);
```

Insert some data:

```
INSERT INTO TUser (name) VALUES 
     ('jack')
    ,('rose')
    ,('peter');


INSERT INTO TMessage(uid, message) VALUES
     (1, 'Hello jack')
    , (1, 'Jack, how are you')
    , (1, 'Good morning jack')
    , (2, 'I love you, rose')
    , (3, 'Peter, please call back')
    , (3, 'What are you doing, Peter');
```

When I run the following LEFT JOIN + ORDER BY query, FileSort shows in the EXPLAIN result:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT *
  FROM        TUser
  LEFT JOIN   TMessage 
  ON          TUser.id=TMessage.uid
  WHERE       TUser.id=3
  ORDER BY    TMessage.id DESC;



id  select_type table    type  possible_keys    key              key_len ref   rows Extra
1   SIMPLE      TUser    const PRIMARY;         PRIMARY          4       const 1    Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      TMessage ref   TMessageIndexUid TMessageIndexUid 4       const 2 \N
```

Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filesort is introduced by the ORDER BY:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN
    -> SELECT *
    ->   FROM        TUser
    ->   LEFT JOIN   TMessage
    ->   ON          TUser.id=TMessage.uid
    ->   WHERE       TUser.id=3
    ->   ORDER BY    TMessage.id DESC;
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TUser    | NULL       | const | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY          | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TMessage | NULL       | ref   | TMessageIndexUid | TMessageIndexUid | 4       | const |    4 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN
    -> SELECT *
    ->   FROM        TUser
    ->   LEFT JOIN   TMessage
    ->   ON          TUser.id=TMessage.uid
    ->   WHERE       TUser.id=3;
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TUser    | NULL       | const | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY          | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TMessage | NULL       | ref   | TMessageIndexUid | TMessageIndexUid | 4       | const |    4 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Since the order by is operating on a LEFT JOIN result, I have no idea on how to avoid this filesort.

If changing LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN is acceptable, that maybe a way to bypass, while missing some User info with no match with TMessages.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN
    -> SELECT *
    ->   FROM        TUser
    ->   INNER JOIN   TMessage
    ->   ON          TUser.id=TMessage.uid
    ->   WHERE       TUser.id=3
    ->   ORDER BY    TMessage.id DESC;
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TUser    | NULL       | const | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY          | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TMessage | NULL       | ref   | TMessageIndexUid | TMessageIndexUid | 4       | const |    2 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Is the FileSort avoidable?

Comment: Is the ORDER BY necessary?

Comment: Post is updated. Is changing to INNER JOIN is acceptable? @Zach

Comment: Thanks. Is it because the `TMessage.id` column may get NULL values using LEFT JOIN, so the index on `TMessage.id` will not be used?

Comment: I am not totally sure about the reason. As I guess, after using LEFT JOIN, the rows may be different from the original left table, so the original index on id will not be usable. In this scenario, it is coincidental that the row number is the same as left table. That depends on the join condition, for example, if 'ON TUser. id != TMessage.uid' is used as s the join condition, row count will be different.

Answer (score -1):

I also don't know about 'filesort'. Then I found out something like,

```
"Anytime a sort can’t be performed from an index, it’s a filesort."
```

Here are the links to refer:

- https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/
- http://s.petrunia.net/blog/?p=24
- [Avoid filesort with INNER JOIN + ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414641/avoid-filesort-with-inner-join-order-by?rq=1)