# SQL Improve Efficiency: LIMIT the amount of FILESORT

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I’m going to explain myself,  with a query like this: (post_id= PRIMARY, blog_id=index )

```
SELECT post_id FROM posts WHERE blog_id IN (2,3,...) ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Update: the ids in IN() could be numerous.
If the DB uses blog_id as key for the query, it has to make a filesort, because the index would look like this:

```
(blog_id,post_id)-> (1,55) (1,59) (1,69) (2,57) (2,71) (2,72) (3,12)
```

If instead of IN() you search for just one id blog_id = 2, it does not need to do any filesort because all the matches are already in order.

The problem that I think it’s happening, not 100% sure but just by looking at the queries execution times, is that if I add a LIMIT 10 the efficient way would be to only catch and filesort the last 10 ids of every blog_id index key match, maybe it already does that, but looks like for a IN (2,3,4) ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 10, it filesorts thousands of ids instead of 30.

I hope I’m just dead wrong because if I am not that is a terrible inefficient mistake.
If I’m right is there any engine or change I could do? even change database. Currently I’m on 10.1.13-MariaDB and the table is InnoDB

Comment: Are you really doing `SELECT post_id`, not `SELECT *`?  It makes a significant difference for _this_ question.

Comment: Yes, since it is a subquery of a bigger one where I select * and joins to other tables, and already in a previous question a year ago I was told that this form was more efficient to do it, and it was. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414641/avoid-filesort-with-inner-join-order-by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL does not have an index that lets you do what you want.

However, you can rewrite the query you have and use the existing index:

```
SELECT p.post_id
FROM ((SELECT post_id
       FROM posts
       WHERE blog_id = 2
       ORDER BY post_id DESC
       LIMIT 10
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT post_id
       FROM posts
       WHERE blog_id = 3
       ORDER BY post_id DESC
       LIMIT 10
      )
     ) p
ORDER BY post_id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Each subquery will use the index.  And a sort on 20 elements is pretty fast.

Comment: Well, the IN() ids can be hundreds and they are dynamic, they change, that was an example. From my point of view I think what I'm saying would be easy and technically possible, so I don't understand why it's not done, does not make sense in my head. By the way I'm with MariaDB now that has new table engines. There is not any possibility?

You say there is not an index that does that, maybe is wrong my understanding of the order of the index? Because the index is right for me, the problem that I'm seeing here is the way the engine searches.

Comment: PD: by "and they are dynamic, they change" I meant the quantity changes, that could be sorted out, but as I said there can be a lot of ids.

Comment: The `UNION` approach is good for a small number of blog_ids; not so good for a large number (N), the overhead of `UNION`, plus the tmp table will be 10*N rows.

Comment: @Vixxs . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  Your question has 2 or 3 ids.  If you have a lot (say hundreds or thousands), then `IN` might not be the best approach.

Comment: You are right. On my defense I would say that the two examples suggest that the number of ids is variable, and that gives a hint that the quantity may be larger and they act as an example. But as I said you’re right and I still can choose this answer or any that answers the non updated answer more correctly.

Comment: @Vixxs . . . The point I want to make is people are happy to help, but strangers can't read minds.  You should ask another question about hundreds of ids, if that is closer to the actual problem.

Comment: Oh, 8.0 has some new Optimizer hints that you can put in the statement.  (I don't know if they would help in _this_ case.)

Comment: @Gordon - Vixxs edited the question rather than starting a new Question.  Perhaps some of the comments should now be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Look at `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`; see if it says "filesort".

Do the following to get details, even for small datasets:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

You do need `INDEX(blog_id, post_id)`.  If you are using InnoDB and the table has

```
PRIMARY KEY(post_id),
INDEX(blog_id)
```

then you do have that composite index.  This is because every secondary index implicitly includes the PK's column(s).

Since you are using MariaDB, see if [*LIMIT ROWS EXAMINED*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/limit-rows-examined/) will do the other thing you asked about.

When the Optimizer sees this:

```
WHERE blog_id IN (2,3)
ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 10
```

and it has both `INDEX(blog_id)` and `INDEX(post_id)`, it makes a decision -- but on limited statistics -- as to which way to go:

Plan A:  Filter on blog_id + filesort, or
Plan B:  scan in post_id order hoping to find 10 rows soon.

Either one is risky.  Plan A, if most or all of the rows are (2,3), will have a big sort.  Plan B, when there are fewer than 10 matching rows, will scan the entire table (or index).

Comment: Yes I tried forcing the primary before, and depending on the test, depending of the number of the posts or if they are too deep into the index, one or the other way perform better, I will have to make a choice by looking at the average query. But I rather not make that choice, and find a way to do what my question suggests, that I imagine will outperform this two choices in almost all queries.

LIMIT ROWS EXAMINED does not look to be made for this, and it produces this fatal error if the number is to low: #1028 - Sort aborted:

Comment: Then I think you need to re-think the "requirements".  Or maybe change the "user expectations".  Can you sacrifice that long list?  The ordering?  Something else?  (Not all performance problems can be solved; you hit a simple to explain, but tough to solve, problem.)